# Which one is correct 你说的对 or 你说得对？

Tags: translation, word-choice

Which one is correct 你说的对 or 你说得对？ Especially to express meaning:

> You are right in terms of ...

Comment: both are:  说的对 what has been said is correct 
说得对 say correctly; tell the truth (feed both to bkrs)

Comment: @user6065 That looks like an answer

Comment: Just a practical tip, sometimes, if you are not sure which one you should choose from 的地得, just pick up 的, you won't be wrong legally.

Comment: The stuctrue of 你说得对 likes 你跑得快 (you run fast), 你说的对=你说的是对的 What you said is right.

Answer (score 9):

Both 你说的对 and 你说得对 could be valid.

你说的对 means 你说的*内容*对：what you said is right.

你说得对 means either 'you said it right' or 'it's right/correct for you to say it'. 得 here is an effect or result complement.

However, 'you are right' should be interpreted as '你是对的'. Specially for "**You are right in terms of xxx**": **在xxx方面，你是对的** or **从xxx角度(来看/来说), 你是对的**.

For example, you are right in terms of time or money: 从时间或金钱的角度来说， 你是对的。